Need help in migrating from fasterxml jackson 2.9 to 2.15
We are upgrading spring boot to latest 3.2.9 which by default includes jackson 2.15. ealrier version was compaitable with jackson 2.9.
I have a task to upgrade jackson library from version 2.9 to 2.15.
can you help me how do i go about it? is there any migration related or breaking changes documented for every version release of jackson? if yes, can you pls point me the right place/ link to the breaking changes etc.
Our project is using databind and annotations packages primarily.
or if i should follow any other approach? pls suggest?

Why is upgrading a task? Upgrade spring boot and jackson will automatically follow. It should be backwards compatible, check the spring boot upgrade guide and jockson releaser notes. If you need to do anything other then just upgrading Spring Boot you are doing it wrong and are managing dependencies you shouldn't be managing manually.
